# Is it possible in selenium enable images after certain step? If in before class is disabled

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, cucumber

I have problem i need to have disabled images for first step in option like this.. it is in before tag:

```
options.addArguments("--blink-settings=imagesEnabled=false");
```

Is it possible to enable it after first step is executed?
I have cucumber java test framework.
Something like adding to step def.

```
options.addArguments("--blink-settings=imagesEnabled=true");
```

Thanks for every advice.